# How to implement byte command class

Tags: c#, class, design-patterns

I'm looking for a guide regarding best practices to implement my class.
My case:
I want to create a class for controlling PTZ cameras. The command is sent through the network as a byte[] to the camera.
There are 2 protocols with different commands and values, so I will create a class for each protocol.

Is it best to create a byte[] for each command and list them in the class and change the values based on the user input. For example:

Protocol A

```
byte[] up =   { 0xff, 0x12, 0x03, 0x04, .... }
byte[] down = { 0xff, 0x1a, 0x03, 0x05, .... }
byte[] left = { 0xff, 0x10, 0x03, 0x02, .... }
byte[] right ={ 0xff, 0x02, 0x03, 0x06, .... }
void setUpValue(byte speed)
{ 
    up[3]=speed;
}
```

or do I dynamically create the byte[] based on the user request?

### **EDIT**

I'm working on creating a library for 2 PTZ controlling protocols and I want to create a class for each protocol. For example, ProcotolAControl & ProcotolBControl.

I want to know the best way to make my code more modular and OOP.

Comment: Could you explain more detail about  `There are 2 protocols with different commands and values`? and what's your expect to solve problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create abstract class `ProcotolControlBase` to be those two class contract, let `ProcotolAControl` and `ProcotolBControl` class inherit  `ProcotolControlBase`.

- `ProcotolAControl` and `ProcotolBControl` make their own detail logic in self-class.
- You can set Procotol default data on `ProcotolAControl` and `ProcotolBControl` Constructor.

look like this.

```
public abstract class ProcotolControlBase {
    protected byte[] _up;
    protected byte[] _down;
    protected byte[] _left;
    protected byte[] _right;

    public void SetUpValue(int index,byte speed)
    {
        _up[index] = speed;
    }

    public void SetDownValue(int index, byte speed)
    {
        _down[index] = speed;
    }
}
public class ProcotolAControl : ProcotolControlBase
{
    public ProcotolAControl() {
        _up = new byte[] { 0xff, 0x12, 0x03, 0x04 };
        _down = new byte[] { 0xff, 0x1a, 0x03, 0x05 };
        _left = new byte[] { 0xff, 0x10, 0x03, 0x02 };
        _right = new byte[] { 0xff, 0x02, 0x03, 0x06 };
    }
}

public class ProcotolBControl : ProcotolControlBase {
    public ProcotolBControl()
    {
        _up = new byte[] { 0xff, 0x12, 0x03, 0x04 };
        _down = new byte[] { 0xff, 0x1a, 0x03, 0x05 };
        _left = new byte[] { 0xff, 0x10, 0x03, 0x02 };
        _right = new byte[] { 0xff, 0x02, 0x03, 0x06 };
    }
}
```

When you use it will be

```
ProcotolControlBase procotol = new ProcotolAControl(); //use ProcotolAControl
ProcotolControlBase procotol1 = new ProcotolBControl(); //use ProcotolBControl
```

Comment: Follow up question, to remove SetValue func, is there away to link array member to a variable. For example,
<br>
byte UpSpeed = 0x01;<br>
Up = new byte[] { 0xff, 0x01, 0x00, 0x08, UpSpeed, 0x00, 0x00 };<br>
UpSpeed = 0x04;<br>
The value of Up[4] will automatically reflect UpSeed value.<br>

<br>
Or do I have to use Events?

Comment: Did you want to change `byte[]` array from user input `byte`?

Comment: Parts of the array. Meaning I instead of changing the array member manually for each command, I change the variable and it will reflect on all the arrays that use it. for example, if I have Speed variable, changing it will change Up, Down, Left and Right arrays at index 3 automatically

Comment: So you only change array at index 3  automatically,or 3 is a example it depends in user input?

Answer (score 1):

The [Template method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) design pattern might be appropiate for your implementation.